# Cakephp 3 save associations belongsToMany

Tags: php, associations, cakephp-3.x

I need to save my associated data from form. Tables stracture look like this:

I have some models which associated with BelongsToMany (model like Users associated with Medias with MediasObjects)
Users:  id, email ...
Books: id, title ...
etc....

Media: id, file ....
MediasObject: id, object_name, object_id, media_id

Form return data like this (after edit User):

```
$data = Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [email] => 'some@email.com'
    ..
    [medias] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
              [id] = 17
            )

        )
)
```

I have User (id=1) and also have Media (id=17), now I need to save association data into MediasObject like this:

```
Array(
  [object_name] => 'Users',
  [object_id] => 1,
  [media_id] => 17

}
```

and I haven't got any idea where should I set 'object_name' value ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `_joinData` property.

```
$data = [
    'id' => 1,
    'media' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            '_joinData' => [
                'object_name' => 'Users'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-join-table